# Can you tell something about a user by "votes cast"?

Tags: discussion, voting

I recently noticed the "Votes Cast" feature present in every user's Stack Overflow account: this feature allows other users to see how many votes a user has cast, and more importantly, what type (upvotes vs downvotes). This prompted me to explore the profiles of other users to try to figure out more about their voting personalities: were they more positive than negative; were they frequent voters, etc.

I noticed most users cast many more downvotes than upvotes, which brings me to a conclusion: that the stack overflow community is more negative than it is positive. In my view, a downvote represents doing something wrong (something that could be improved on), while an upvote represents doing something right (something that should keep happening). In this case, a neutral community really should have an equal number of downvotes than upvotes. However, it seems that most Stack Overflow members are overly cynical, trying to condemn rather than collaborate.

Just some food for thought.

Comment: Are you asking a question, or just making an observation?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know. But you are an optimist (judging from your upvote/downvote ratio).

Comment: Votes on deleted posts are counted in "votes cast", but deleted posts are *deleted*, and are not visible to most users. The fact that you see people casting more downvotes than upvotes is evidence of the tremendous amounts of crap and spam that people downvote and are eventually deleted.

Comment: Personally, I would like to see the "votes cast" split up among posts that are deleted vs. undeleted. To the untrained eye, someone who casts a lot of downvotes will appear to be a "hater" rather than a "janitor".

Comment: See my answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220580/135615 . You really can't tell anything from someone's voting record, because there's tons of garbage (spam, trolling, pure gibberish) that comes in and is deleted from the site. Also, the site is inundated with very bad or off topic questions every day, so I don't think it's safe to make the assumption that there's as much good content as bad.

Comment: By your analysis, you would call me an overly cynical member :) On the contrary, it's because of the fact that I do a lot of reviews and unfortunately a lot of low-quality stuff comes on SO everyday.

Comment: Haha you're right! I call it the grumpy developer syndrome. I opened up a thread with a similar premise. Myself? I've cast over 1450 votes and nearly everyone has been positive. Maybe 1 or 2 were negative lol.

Comment: Just adding to the statistics: right now 4500 upvotes and about 1500 downvotes.

Answer (score 24):

> a neutral community really should have an equal number of downvotes than upvotes

This assertion rests on a number of shaky assumptions.

1. *Downvotes and upvotes have equal, but opposing value.*  For the most part, they do not.  We don't even assign the same absolute point value to them.
2. *Community members make more positive contributions than they do negative ones.*  For the most part, this is not true.  Altruistic contributions consider the needs of the community.  The vast majority of new posts only consider the needs of the individual posting them.
3. *Answers have the same overall qualities as questions.*  For the most part, this isn't true either.  Good questions are clearly asked, interesting to others, and answerable.  Good answers answer the question being asked, are informative, and are not used for anything except answering the question.  The community is better at answering questions than it is at asking them.

Answer (score 14):

> This prompted me to explore the profiles of other users to try to figure out more about their voting personalities: were they more positive than negative; were they frequent voters, etc.
>
> I noticed most users cast many more downvotes than upvotes, which brings me to a conclusion: that the stack overflow community is more negative than it is positive.

Stack Overflow has [3.4 million registered users](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday). You cannot possibly obtain an accurate, credible measure of the overall community's voting habits by just poking around the profiles of a handful of random users. If you want to get a more credible, accurate picture, then you can try using a query in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) (SEDE) to pull some hard numbers instead. It will make your arguments stronger and more convincing.

Actually, you can't really get this information through SEDE at all, because [deleted posts aren't included in its data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se), so only Stack Exchange employees themselves are able to access the overall picture of what voting is like around Stack Overflow as a whole.

Emphasis mine,

> In my view, a downvote represents doing something wrong (something that could be improved on), while an upvote represents doing something right (something that should keep happening). In this case, **a neutral community really should have an equal number of downvotes than upvotes**.

You're assuming that the [**7000-8000 *new* questions *per day***](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-questionsperday) that flood Stack Overflow are 50% "good" questions, and 50% "bad" questions. Do you have any numbers to back that assumption up with? Because it may just as well be the case that 90% of questions are bad, and only 10% are good. Or maybe it's the reverse.

Also, you could argue that the overall voting patterns around Stack Overflow reflect the quality *of the content* that is posted, not the quality of the community.

Comment: Deleted posts are now part of SEDE though.