# Votes cast bug?

Tags: support, voting

I wonder if there is a bug in the Vote count system.

When I click my profile, scroll down, and look at the Votes Cast number, it says **255**.

But when I click on it to be directed to the Votes Cast Overview, it says **180** Votes Cast. I have selected the *all* tab, so the total Vote Cound should be displayed.

Am I getting this wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: The Votes Cast shows for deleted posts as well.

Comment: Related: [Can you tell something about a user by “votes cast”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267733/456814).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The stats on your profile include all the votes you've ever cast, **even on deleted posts**. However, the actual votes tab where you can view the votes you've cast does **not** display deleted posts in the list*, so it will only show you the number of votes on posts which haven't since been deleted.

<sup>** Note that the delete and undelete vote subsections of that overview **do** show deleted posts.*</sup>

Comment: Then, why, does the Votes Cast (with the list) shows a difference when I hit vote button, whereas the Votes cast (under the impact) does not respond?

Comment: In addition... the Vote counter for earning a badge is a value which is neither of the other two

Comment: So, which counter is consider for badge purposes?