# Why are there three different numbers of votes cast in my profile?

Tags: bug, voting, profile-page

In my profile, I can see three numbers which indicate my **votes cast**: 
295, 264, and 299. Why are they not the same?

[image: Profile screenshot 1]

[image: Profile screenshot 2]

Comment: The reason is the different places count different things. I know there was a meta discussion that had all 3, and I'm looking for it, but this at least explains the one under your flags and the "votes" tab: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267957/votes-cast-bug

Comment: The 'votes cast' in the votes tab does not show / count votes on deleted posts.  I have "8,456 votes cast" in the top and only "2,616 Votes Cast" in the votes all tab.

Comment: Please consider adding this to [the master bugs list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list)

Comment: Please report issues and comments with the new profiles here on Meta Stack Exchange: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votes are counted towards the Civic Duty badge as they are cast **(299)**. These are cached and eventually added to your running total on the right side **(295)**. The caching explains the lower total on the right. Entering your "Votes Cast" section though **(264)**, the count excludes any votes cast on deleted posts. So you have cast 35 votes on things that were eventually deleted, and 4 votes that will be added to your right-side total in due time.

As [MichaelT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/289086/michaelt) mentioned, you only see deleted votes cast on close and delete vote tabs

Comment: Even with 10k rep (unless they've changed it with this profile update) doesn't show up/down votes on deleted content. You only see deleted votes cast on close and delete vote tabs.

Comment: @MichaelT Good to know, and updated. Thanks.