# Why are we closing questions simply because they "belong on MSE"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, meta

I have noticed a small trend recently that is contrary to what was originally discussed when MSO and MSE was split (see: [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them)) and I am trying to understand if this is because of a misunderstanding on the part of a few users or if this is because the community as a whole does not want these questions.

Some recent examples (a few that are about the new profile page which does have a [home on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list), but is still contrary to the guidance I linked initially):

- [Favorites in new profile: box not wide enough for "answers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290349/favorites-in-new-profile-box-not-wide-enough-for-answers) ***(now reopened)***
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290343/profile-badges-dont-match-the-badge-page ***(now reopened)***
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290070/details-about-the-moderator-election ***(now reopened)***
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290341/in-the-new-profile-a-comment-that-i-already-commented-after-was-shown-as-unread ***(now reopened)***
- [Why are there three different numbers of votes cast in my profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290333/votes-cast-not-the-same-in-my-profile-there-is-3) ***(now reopened)***
- [Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290394/apparently-this-user-prefers-to-keep-an-air-of-mystery-about-them) ***(now reopened)***

Should we be closing these questions?  If so, then perhaps it is worth discussing a feature request for cross-meta duplicates either as a custom close reason or as a real duplicate feature because the reason that is being used is

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or **the software that powers the Stack Exchange network**, within the scope defined in the help center.

And that is an inaccurate close reason because of the point that I bolded above.

Comment: Why, indeed? It's a mystery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to come clean and say that I was a part of this problem. At the time, I was unaware that [problems could be reported on any Meta site if they dealt with the Stack Exchange network in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them).

I'm pretty sure I spearheaded close votes on all of those, as you can see from the comments I left on each. I sincerely apologize for my rash actions without proper clarification and promise to be more through in my research before voting to close questions in haste again.

Comment: Thanks for stepping up.  I did notice that but intentionally did not mention it during the primary election out of concern of influencing the results.  Yes, SE did ask for feedback in the post you linked, but I think the best solution would be to suggest they post it there.  If they don't (and you think the feedback/bug is of some value), you can post it to the MSE post itself.  At least, that is why I would do for these types of posts.

Answer (score 15):

It seems like one or two users were under the impression that if the question is about more than SO (as in pertains to all sites), that it should be closed. Some other users probably didn't pay close enough attention while reviewing in the close queue, and before you know it, many questions were incorrectly closed.

You are right. All those questions you linked to are on-topic here on Meta.SO and should not be closed, and definitely not closed for *This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center.* close reason.

Answer (score -6):

My understanding is that this is a special case. The SE developers expected numerous bug reports immediately after the new profile pages were deployed on most of the child sites. To make tracking and handling the flood of bug reports easier, they requested to have them all posted in a single place on MSE.

If this is indeed just an effect of this special situation, I don't think there's a need for a policy or procedure change.

Comment: But not all are about the new profile (but most are)

Comment: @psubsee2003 5 out of the 6 you listed were about the new profile. For the other one (or in any case where it makes sense), you can simply cast reopen votes. Questions get wrongly closed on a fairly regular basis, and reopened if users disagree with the closure. I still don't see enough data to suggest a new pattern, as long as you don't count the new profile bug reports.

Comment: Actually 4 were about the profile.  The 5th only looked like it was about the profile because the OP thought it was about the profile, but actually was not