# Can I see a list of answers I voted up?

Tags: discussion, android-app

I can't find an answer that I really liked, I might have voted on it so I'm hoping I can view answers that I voted on.

As a rookie, I tried out several ways and I wonder whether StackOverflow has provided this feature.

If so, would you mind telling me how to do?
If not, is there an alternative solution to this?

Comment: you have to vote first :p

Comment: Go to your profile and check the votes tab.

Comment: As for alternatives if you didn't vote, you can try searching your browser history (although if it's anything like mine the number of results on SO would make that prohibitive). In future, you can "favourite" questions that are particularly relevant to you.

Comment: As a reminder, meta.stackoverflow is for questions that are specific to the inner-workings of the Stack Overflow *site* alone. This question seems to be concerned with the Stack Exchange *network*, and thus should be asked on [meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).

Comment: @chharvey You should read [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them) by Tim Post concerning users posting such questions on MSO. He very explicitly says that this is perfectly okay to ask on MSO.

Comment: @Kendra — yes, with the understanding that “we'll handle moving it over for you”. But why ask a question on a sub-site meta only for it to be migrated, when you could just simply ask it on meta.SE in the first place?

Comment: @chharvey You pulled only part of that quote: _"**if it needs to get more attention on the network meta**, we'll handle moving it over for you."_ (emphasis mine) In other words _if the mods feel it needs input from the entire network_ they will move the post. Otherwise, it's completely fine to have here. Some of these posts _don't need eyes from the entire network_ to be answered. All they need is someone who's familiar with the system. Why send a user to a site they're unfamiliar with when they can get that answer here and it be on-topic?

Comment: @chharvey See also: [Why are we closing questions simply because they “belong on MSE”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290551/why-are-we-closing-questions-simply-because-they-belong-on-mse?lq=1) which was asked because people not only misunderstood this, but they were closing questions because of the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10):

You can see what you upvoted by [clicking on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote) if you're logged in.

Comment: Wasn't the question about Android app (which by the way is lot different from the website, I stopped using after few days)?

Comment: @WandMaker Well Martijn Pieters added that tag in because the question originally vaguely had an 'android' tag on it, I don't really see any hint in the original unedited text that this is specifically about the app to be honest. in any case: the question itself allows alternative solutions so this answer remains valid no matter what the truth is.

Comment: Very helpful! I was about to ask about it and found your answer and link. Have spent the better part of an hour looking for an answer on SO. After clicking on the link, found it in less than 1 minute. Thanks.