# How did I get the Civic Duty Badge?

Tags: support, badges

I just got the badge [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty?userid=1870760) for voting 300 or more times. Looking at [my votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870760/gill-bates?tab=votes) on my profile though it says that I have only voted 238 times.

Now, math was never one of my strong points but as far as I know 238 < 300.

So why did I get this badge?

Comment: see also: [Votes cast bug?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267957/votes-cast-bug) and [Are downvotes on deleted posts counted in the profile vote count?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284843/165773)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the little grey box on [your profile's Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870760/gill-bates?tab=topactivity) tab you voted 298 times, which is more or less 300, considering it's a cached value.

In the "votes" tab (which is not public btw) only votes on non-deleted posts are shown, so that might be a significant lower value.

Also make sure you sum up the vote count of your up- and down-votes.

Comment: TIL votes are not public. Good point on the deleted post, that might be the case.

Comment: do i have to cast 300 votes in a same day to get civic duty badge?

Comment: or I can do it on multiple days?

Comment: @ZobiaKanwal it's over multiple days